RNS string action in complex coordinates
The action for the Ramond-Neveu-Schwarz string in conformal gauge $h_{\alpha \beta}=\eta_{\alpha \beta}$ of the world-sheet is (for $\alpha '=1/2$ or $T=1/\pi$) $$S=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\int d^2 \sigma \Big(\partial_{\alpha}X_{\mu}\partial^{\alpha }X^{\mu}+\bar{\psi}^{\mu}\rho^{\alpha}\partial_{\alpha}\psi_{\mu}\Big).$$ How can we get the Euclideanized conformal-gauge action as follows? $$S=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int d^2 z\Big( 2\partial X^{\mu}\bar{\partial}X_{\mu}+\frac{1}{2}\psi^{\mu}\bar{\partial}\psi_{\mu}+\frac{1}{2}\tilde{\psi}^{\mu}\partial \tilde{\psi}_{\mu}\Big)$$ in complex coordinates $z=e^{2(\tau -i\sigma)}$ and $\bar{z}=e^{2(\tau +i\sigma)}$. I got the metric as $$h_{\alpha \beta}=\begin{pmatrix}0 & \frac{1}{4z\bar{z}}\\ \frac{1}{4z\bar{z}} & 0\end{pmatrix}$$ from Euclidean metrix $\delta_{\alpha \beta }$ on the world-sheet, but I couldn't get the second action $S$.
